# Apply multi-middleware for same action in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have 2 roles: **admin** and **agent**, and I have a search page. I want to allow 2 roles to access this page.

So if an admin logs in then it can access the search page, and if an agent logs in then it can access the search page as well.

In the `route.php` file I am doing the following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
  Route::post('customer/search', 'CustomersController@search'); 
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'agent'], function(){
  Route::post('customer/search', 'CustomersController@search'); 
});
```

In this case an admin can not access the search page.

And if reverse the middleware like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'agent'], function(){
  Route::post('customer/search', 'CustomersController@search'); 
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
  Route::post('customer/search', 'CustomersController@search'); 
});
```

the agent can not access the search page.

So, how can I allow the admin and agent roles to both access the search page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each middleware checks its own role (if the user is an `admin` and respectively an `agent`), then the first executed middleware will always restrict access to the last in one of the cases. There's no way around that if you do a separate check in each middleware. You perhaps need a common middleware that validates all roles that are allowed to access the search route. So something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'searchRoles'], function()
{
    Route::post('customer/search', 'CustomersController@search'); 
});
```